# three counts in one sql query

Tags: mysql, select, count

```
ID    FRUIT

1     Apple
2     Orange
3     Apple
4     Pear
5     Apple
6     Pear
7     Pear
```

---

I want to do a count of each fruit in a table. There are only three fruit, i only need totals.

I know how to do a SELECT COUNT(*) but not all three in one query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select fruit, count(id) from table group by fruit
```

Comment: such a short efficient query, and exactly what i was after!!